# SQL - CASE NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql

```
case gg.finalgrade
 when NULL
   then 'Nothing to Show'
 else gg.finalgrade
end as 'Grade'
```

Many of my gg.finalgrade values is shown in the database as NULL, but the above statement simply ignores those values and does not print anything. I want it to show 'Nothing to Show' when the value is NULL.

I have looked at some examples on SO but can't seem to get them to work.

Thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce `COALESCE(gg.finalgrade, 'Nothing to show')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother using a case expression for this, MySQL has a funciton built in called `IFNULL()`

Have a look here for an example of how this works:

[SQL NULL Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

The syntax is:

```
SELECT IFNULL(gg.finalgrade,'Nothing to Show')
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL this expression is never true:

```
null = null
```

So comparing two values with null will always be false

You can use something like this

```
coalesce(gg.finalgrade, 'Nothing to show')
```

or

```
case
when gg.finalgrade is null
then 'Nothing to show'
else gg.finalgrade
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using IS NULL:

```
case 
 when gg.finalgrade IS NULL
   then 'Nothing to Show'
 else gg.finalgrade
end
```

Comment: thanks but this did not work for me for some reason, i get an error :(